# Long compilation for an initialization of large vector of vectors

Tags: c++, large-data

I have a very large constant 2-dimension array to store in a C++ file.
Dimensions are about 1,000,000 rows and 2 to 10 elements in each row, with `uint8_t` as elements.

The number of elements in each row being variable, I wanted to use vectors for the rows, and possibly vector of vectors for the full array, so I tried 3 ways for the initialization

```
const uint8_t array[1000000][10] = {{...},...,{...}};              /* Case 1 */
const std::vector<uint8_t> array[1000000] = {{...},...,{...}};     /* Case 3 */
const std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> array = {{...},...,{...}}; /* Case 2 */
```

The compilation using g++ is very different between the three cases.

Case 1 compiles fast, but I fear that some space is wasted to keep the alignment? Is this different for Cases 2 and 3?

Case 2 and Case 3 take a very long time to compile. Adding `-ftime-report` shows that the g++ "phase opt and generate" step is taking a very long time.

Any idea what to change in the code and/or to make the compilation faster?

Comment: Why do you need such large constant vectors?

Comment: These are the outputs of a very long computation, which need to be hardcoded into the code to avoid recomputation.

Comment: You can write the 'whole data' in a separate assembly file, and link that file and c++ sources into single binary. This will be extremely fast compared to your case.

Comment: `sizeof(vector)` is basically `2 *sizeof(T*) + std::size_t` which should be superior than `10` with your compiler/architecture. so you should not lose space for Case1 (but should should keep track of inner "array size")

Comment: *"compiles fast"* Is it really compile time comparison and not runtime timing (memory allocation overhead) ?

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, this is really the **compilation time**, and not the execution time of the compiled code.

Comment: @align: Do you mean writing the array content into an assembly file? How would this be different from Case 1?

Comment: @user51957 It would be different because you need to compile assembly file for only one time.

Comment: @align: I can also put the const array in a single .cpp file and compile this one alone, right?

Comment: @user51957 Yes, of course, but this way is still 'extremely' fast, compared to cpp file. But it is not that important maybe.

Comment: @align: The order of magnitudes are way different. If assembly takes 1 sec to compile, the external cpp file could maybe take 2-3, while the vector case might be in the 1000s. I'm willing to spend more than 2-3 in compilation time, but not to loose a huge factor in code size.

Comment: Does `std::array<std::array<uint8_t, 10>, 1000000> array = {..};` also take time ? I suspect compiler has to check each `initializer_list` in class cases.

Comment: @Jarod42: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to me that `= {...}` does not work directly for an `std::array`. So I used `array{{...}}` for the initialization. Using that, the compilation is indeed fast.   Is there a way to help the compiler for each `initializer_list`, e.g., by providing the actual size of the small vectors?

Comment: Maybe prepend `std::initializer_list<std::uint8_t>` before each internal initializer_list...

Answer (score 3):

You can write the 'whole data' in a separate assembly file, and link that file and c++ sources into single binary. This will be extremely fast compared to your case.

Sample asembly file:

```
 .globl large_data
    .section .rodata
    .p2align 5
    .type large_data, "object"
    .size large_data, <insert_size_here>
large_data:

    .byte 77,90,144,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,255,2..... and so on
```

Sample C++ code:

```
extern const uint8_t large_data [];
```

If you link these source together, you can directly access to data, for e.g:

```
uint8_t x = large_data[0];
```

In this way, you would need to compile assembly file only once.

Comment: Assume for the sake of the example that every row of `A[][]` contains 1 element except one row that contains 10 elements. I would then cast your extern variable as `(uint8_t (*)[10])` and then there are a significant unused space in the assembly file, no?